# Calling C# code behind method using javascript without ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have 2 buttons in my asp.net File

```
<asp:Button ID="BTN_Send_LA" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="ConfirmSendData()"></asp:Button>
//The button the client will click

<asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="" OnClick="BTN_Send_LA_Click"/>
//Dummy Button for the JS .click()
```

And here is my Js part:

```
function ConfirmSendData() {
    var r = confirm("Êtes vous bien: " + document.getElementById("<%=DDL_LaveurLA.ClientID%>").options[document.getElementById("<%=DDL_LaveurLA.ClientID%>").selectedIndex].text + " sinon veuillez changer dans le champ spécifié 'Laveur'");

    if (r == true) {

        var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= UploadButton.ClientID %>");
        clickButton.click();

        //$('UploadButton').trigger('click'); TEST 1
        //__doPostBack not working aswell

    }
}
```

So here what i expect to be done:

1. The client click the first button (Trigger the JS)    => Works
2. R is true => Works
3. The JS part trigger the Onclick of UploadButton => Don't Work

I don't understand why this method doesn't work as it seems to be the general approach most other answers take on StackOverflow?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I've tried every solutions proposed below and now i have weird problems:

When I click on the client button, 1 of the 3 following things happens randomly (route followed with the debugger)

1: The button click do a blank postback (IsPostBack == true) 
   event OnClick="BTN_Send_LA_Click" not fired

2: The button click do a blank postback (IsPostBack == false) 
   event OnClick="BTN_Send_LA_Click" not fired

3: The button fire the event OnClick="BTN_Send_LA_Click" of the dummy button properly.

I don't understand why. When i click directly on the dummy button, everything works fine

**Everytime I do a CTRL+F5, the first time I click the client button will work 100% (event fired)**

something else: in my event BTN_Send_LA_Click(), I change the background color of multiple controls (lightgreen)

1: If I click on the dummy button => the background color of the controls are changed

2: If I click on the client button and even if the BTN_Send_LA_Click() is fired, the background color doesn't change.

Why ? I'm totally lost on this one

Updated code:

```
        function ConfirmSendData()
     {
            /*
            var dd = document.getElementById("<%=DDL_LaveurLA.ClientID%>");
            var txt = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
            var r = confirm("Êtes vous bien: " + txt + " sinon veuillez changer dans le champ spécifié 'Laveur'"); */

            var r = confirm("Êtes vous bien: " + document.getElementById("<%=DDL_LaveurLA.ClientID%>").options[document.getElementById("<%=DDL_LaveurLA.ClientID%>").selectedIndex].text + " sinon veuillez changer dans le champ spécifié 'Laveur'");

            if (r == true) {
                //$("#<%=UploadButton.ClientID%>").click();

                var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= UploadButton.ClientID %>");
                clickButton.click();

            }
            return false;  
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("#<%=UploadButton.ClientID%>").click();` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that generally questions are kept at a fairly professional level so you wouldn't expect to see words like `guyz` in a question.

Comment: Which part doesn't work, getting the element or firing the click event? What does clickEvent contain after its assignment?

Comment: @aw04 the firing event occur randomly (check updated part)

Answer (score 4):

You've got it all right except:

1. You need a closing `}` on your `if` statement.
2. `ConfirmSendData()` needs to `return false` to prevent the first button from submitting.

i.e.

```
function ConfirmSendData() {
    var r = confirm("Êtes vous bien...");
    if (r == true) {
        var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= UploadButton.ClientID %>");
        clickButton.click();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good spot @stovroz.  Although it also needs `return` to be added to the `OnClientClick` as well

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I have updated the initial question since it works randomly

Answer (score 2):

You have the following commented out, which I presume means you've tried it and it didn't work...

```
//$('UploadButton').trigger('click'); TEST 1
```

jQuery needs the `#` character before the ID of the element to find it, so try this instead...

```
$("#<%=UploadButton.ClientID%>").click();
```

I would also update the first part of your function slightly to a more readable (and efficient) version by only finding the dropdown element once...

```
var dd = document.getElementById("<%=DDL_LaveurLA.ClientID%>");
var txt = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].text;
var r = confirm("Êtes vous bien: " + txt + " sinon veuillez changer dans le champ spécifié 'Laveur'");
```

Comment: Isn't this just the jquery equivalent of the javascript code above?

Comment: Probably @aw04, but I know I've had cross-browser trouble in the past with `.click();` (can't remember exactly what now) so tend to favour the jQuery version.  You're probably correct, so happy to withdraw the answer if proven

Comment: I was just curious about the reasoning, it's still a helpful answer IMO.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I have updated the initial question since it works randomly (with your solution)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$("#<%=UploadButton.ClientID%>")` instead of `$('UploadButton')` because `asp:Button` elements generates not in element with just id `UploadButton`

```
function ConfirmSendData() {
    var r = confirm("Êtes vous bien: " + document.getElementById("<%=DDL_LaveurLA.ClientID%>").options[document.getElementById("<%=DDL_LaveurLA.ClientID%>").selectedIndex].text + " sinon veuillez changer dans le champ spécifié 'Laveur'");

    if (r == true) {

        var clickButton = document.getElementById("<%= UploadButton.ClientID %>");
        clickButton.click();

        // alternative variant for jquery
        // $("#<%=UploadButton.ClientID%>").click();
    }

}
```

also another thing that function `ConfirmSendData` needs to `return false` to prevent the submitting data by first button

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't explain why the javascript part isn't working. You're example just does the same thing again with jquery.

Comment: @aw04 it doesn't work because element not found by jquery selector ```$('UploadButton')```, because this is ```asp:Button``` with dynamically ```ID="UploadButton"```

Comment: I get that, and you're right of course, but I was talking about the javascript code above that essentially does the same thing.

Comment: @aw04 the first js code is a native js, and the second one is a jquery equivalent of it. They have different only sign ```#``` which needs for jquery for finding elements by id

Comment: Yes but you didn't change the native javascript part. If it's not working, what makes you think the jquery alternative will?

Comment: aah... I got you. I've wrote 2 implementation of 1 thing. But I've confused on line ```$('UploadButton').trigger('click'); TEST 1``` and fixed it. Of course enough on of this implementation. I'll fix my answer with comment line

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, I have updated the initial question since it works randomly (with your solution)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
__doPostBack('<%= UploadButton.UniqueID %>', '');
```